# Dropdown list with roles for users when register

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, user-roles

i am trying to implement a registration form where a user will register as a user or as a pet owner. I'm using the registration form which comes with MVC5 and i just added a role field. I have followed many online tutorials and answered question but nothing solved my problem. Am I not returning the correct view?

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN8OM.png)

My Register view

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, Model.RoleList, "Select Role", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

GET: /Account/Register in AccountController

[AllowAnonymous]

```
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        var roles = context.Roles.Select(r => r.Name);
        var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel
        {
            RoleList = new SelectList(roles)
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

// POST: /Account/Register

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Role);
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        var roles = context.Roles.Select(r => r.Name);
        model.RoleList = new SelectList(roles);
        return View(model);
    }


  public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
```

RegisterViewModel

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a role")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do to build a List of Select Items...
 declare:

```
 public List<SelectListItem> WarehouseSelectItems;
```

Build in constructor:

```
 public CreateModel(UPEIntranet.Models.UPEIntranetContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            var WarehouseSelectItemsLinq = _context.Warehouse.Select(wn => new SelectListItem
            {

               Value  = wn.ID.ToString(),
                Text = wn.WarehouseName

        });
            WarehouseSelectItems = WarehouseSelectItemsLinq.ToList();

        }
```

Use on page:

```
 <select asp-for="Inventory.WarehouseID" asp-items="Model.WarehouseSelectItems"></select>
```